# Phrase generator keeps repeating the same phrase

Tags: c#

I'm very new to C# and I figured making this would be a fun little challenge. After a lot of searching for other posts that had the same problem I did, none were able to help me. Every time I debug it, the phrase is different, however while debugging, it repeats the same phrase, rather than it being different every time.

```
using System;

public class Program
{

    static String[] nouns = new String[3] { "He", "She", "It" };
    static String[] adjectives = new String[5] { "loudly", "quickly", "poorly", "greatly", "wisely" };
    static String[] verbs = new String[5] { "climbed", "danced", "cried", "flew", "died" };
    static Random rnd = new Random();
    static int noun = rnd.Next(0, nouns.Length);
    static int adjective = rnd.Next(0, adjectives.Length);
    static int verb = rnd.Next(0, verbs.Length);

    static void Main()
    {
        for (int rep = 0; rep < 5; rep++ )
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", nouns[noun], adjectives[adjective], verbs[verb]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Static variables are only initialized once, when your program first loads.

You need `noun`, `adjective`, and `verb` to be (re)generated each time you print a new phrase - so you should move them inside your loop, like this:

```
static void Main()
{
    for (int rep = 0; rep < 5; rep++ )
    {
        int noun = rnd.Next(0, nouns.Length);
        int adjective = rnd.Next(0, adjectives.Length);
        int verb = rnd.Next(0, verbs.Length);
        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", nouns[noun], adjectives[adjective], verbs[verb]);
    }
}
```

This way, you generate new random values each time you run through the loop.